# Book 2: How do I get Abby to talk to me in Chapter 4: Dreaming?

Tags: dreamfall-chapters

In Book 2 of Dreamfall Chapters, I'm stuck in Chapter 4: Dreaming.

I have two quests going on:

1. Bring some information to Mira, but a bot is fixing Mira's front door and the game tells me to come back later.
2. Find information about Abby to get her to tell me where I can find Hannah.

The problem is, nothing in the room Abby is in tells me anything and randomly wandering around town hasn't helped either.

There's are four manhole covers I can remove.  One is welded shut, one is stuck partway open (too small for my character), one is watched by a policeman who threatens to arrest me, and the last is where Abby is.

How do I find the information to get Abby to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have to open the manhole cover guarded by the policeman.  One of the advertising droids floats by every so often.

Stand on/near the manhole cover you want to open, then talk to the droid as it passes by.  Ask it to give you the Full Sales pitch and it will block the sightline of the guard, allowing you to open the manhole and go inside.